# Apply GDB FrameDecorator when stepping

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

I've written a frame filter that applies a `FrameDecorator` object to all frames, and it works for backtraces (when using the `bt` command). However, when I use `up`, `down`, or explicitly go to a frame like `f 0`, gdb prints the undecorated frame.

Is there a way to always apply a `FrameDecorator` even when stepping through frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a requested feature but hasn't been implemented yet.  There's a bit of discussion in the [gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18567).

One temporary option might be a stop hook that does `bt 1`.  But this is likely to be somewhat intrusive.